# Making my wordpress the_post_thumbnail link to permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to merge two lines of code, and being a code noob, am inevitably having trouble. I would like to make my post thumbnail link to the permalink with the supplied lightwindow class. I also have to keep the echo's.

Here is the original code:

```
echo '<li>'; the_post_thumbnail('blog-post-thumb'); echo '</li>';
```

Here's what I'd like to integrate.

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="lightwindow"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `php` concatenate something like this:

`echo "<a class='lightwindow' href='".the_permalink()."'><li>".the_post_thumbnail('blog-post-thumb')."</li></a>";`

That way you only have to use `echo` once instead of a bunch times.

Which is unnecessary.